# Why would Xcode not use the build configuration settings from my xcconfig file?

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcconfig

EDIT: I figured one could have this problem with any build configuration setting, not just `OTHER_LDFLAGS` and I've changed the title accordingly and removed irrelevant details from the question.

I have a simple Xcode project MyApp. MyApp.xcconfig is set as the configuration file for Debug builds. It has one line:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -force_load /foo/bar
```

Though it knows MyApp.xcconfig sets `OTHER_LDFLAGS` Xcode doesn't want to use that setting. A blank space, instead of the value in MyApp.xcconfig, is highlighted in green in the build settings (see the bottom rows labelled "Other Linker Flags"):

[image]

Why is this the case? From what I've read, it seems like the resolved setting should be the one from the .xcconfig file. Is there a way to make it so?

I've also found that other settings in the xcconfig do resolve. But not `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Offtopic: Xcode 7 is available.

Comment: Maybe try using `-ObjC -force_load ...`

Comment: Have you looked in the build log to see if the settings are actually being applied?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes and they aren't

Comment: @l'L'l tried with no luck

Comment: It looks like the `release` version has no flags, so be sure to set them there also.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem build setting (in this case `OTHER_LDFLAGS`) is being assigned an empty string, `""`, in MyApp's `project.pbxproj` file. Xcode sees that assignment and instead of ignoring it, overwrites your xcconfig setting. The solution is to delete the line in `project.pbxproj`.

• From the command line, open  `MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` in a text editor, e.g. Vim. In it you'll see Xcode keeps a bunch of information needed to build MyApp, including build configuration settings that you set in Xcode's UI.

• Scroll to the `XCBuildConfiguration section`. There you'll see your problem build setting (in this case `OTHER_LDFLAGS`) being assigned an empty string. Delete that line and save the file.

```
/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */
            .
            .
            .
            3729FD9E18B776ECB0A1990 /* Debug */ = {
                    isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
                    baseConfigurationReference = 4820F7A08BBB17C8164733A /* MyApp.xcconfig */;
                    buildSettings = {

                       /// delete this line ///
                         OTHER_LDFLAGS = "";

                    };
                    name = Debug;
            };
            .
            .
            .
/* End XCBuildConfiguration section */
```

Comment: Or you can select the cell in Xcode Project editor and hit Delete.

Comment: An annoying bug that - in XCode 11 I couldn't delete the cell in the UI had to edit the project file

Comment: select the entire row and hit delete works